# Some trig question about constraint with tangent and sine

Tags: trigonometry

$(0\le a \le1)$, $(0\le\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2})$  
$\;\tan\theta = \frac{a \sqrt{1-a^2}}{1-a^2}$, and in the end I want to say $\;\sin\theta=a $

$($left$)\,= \tan\theta\\\;=\frac{\sin\theta}{cos\theta}\\\;=\frac{\sin\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\\\;=\frac{\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}{1-\sin^2\theta}\\
$

$ $then, $\frac{\sin\theta\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}{1-\sin^2\theta}=\frac{a\sqrt{1-a^2}}{1-a^2}$

So, what I want to know is  simple. From the last formula, Can I say
$\;\sin\theta=a\;$?  
 Or there's some rules or some constraint that I'm missing so I can't do that.

Comment: Hint: square your last equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin \theta$ is indeed equal to $a$ in this case, but you cannot just directly say that this is the only possible solution which $\sin \theta$ has in this equation.We'll need to prove this.

Since $a \neq 1$ and $\sin \theta \neq 1$, we get

$\frac{\sin \theta}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 \theta}} = \frac{a}{\sqrt{1 - a^2}}$
It is clear that $\sin\theta$ and $a$ are of the same sign. Now, squaring both sides, and simplifying, we get
$a^2 = \sin^2(\theta)$

$a = sin\theta$ or $a = -\sin\theta$.
But, because of squaring the equation, we'll have to check for extra solutions. Since $a$ and $\sin\theta$ are of the same sign, we can say that  the only solutions is $\sin \theta = a$